# Ruby on Rails filterrific gem simple filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, filterrific

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and currently trying to set up an easy search with filterrific. But all examples I can find are much more complicated then mine and I'm a bit confused:

I have a model where I store Bank Holidays. I want to filter the output so the user just sees one year, should default to current year.

Therefore I created a scope in my model:

```
  selected_year = Date.today.year
  scope :year, -> {
  where("YEAR(holiday_date) = #{selected_year}")
  }
```

All examples for filterrific have found exspect that a user wants to search matching different values in related databases.

Any hint on how to filter just simple one value?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to allow the scope to receive an argument like so

```
scope :year, ->(year) { where("YEAR(holiday_date) = #{year}") }
```

Then you can call `Model.year(1986)` etc.